# Do sockets persist between function calls?

Tags: c, function, sockets, network-programming

In the C language, you have local variables in functions that are destroyed when the function returns (they arn't accessible anymore, unless you pass around pointers obviously).

What happens to sockets? Specifcially, if I create a socket in 1 function, can I pass around the sockid and bind it in another, listen in another, and accept in another?

From what I can see this should work, but I'm not an expert in C.

Comment: Socket descriptors are just like file descriptors.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem doing that.  For example:

```
int sock = my_socket();
my_bind(sock);
my_listen(sock);
int connected_sock = my_connect(sock);
my_read(connected_sock);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *if I create a socket in 1 function, can I pass around the sockid and bind it in another, listen in another, and accept in another?*

Yes, you can. when you *create* a socket what you get is an socket file descriptor. You can pass that value to other functions, just like you can pass *any* other value (excluding `return`ing address of local variables, to be exact).

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as telling that you can never pass address of local variables. You can pass around addresses of local variables as long as the code that uses them does not outlive their scope.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Thanks for pointing. I actually meant `return`ing. Updated. :-)